# How do I refer to a Python Class by its name

Tags: python, flask

I have the following in my amin/views.py:

```
from flask import render_template
from .models import User, Role
from flask-classful import FlaskView

....
class BaseView(FlaskView):
    def __init__(self, template, class_name):
        self.template = template
        self.target_class = ???class_name  

    def get_all_records(self):
        return self.target_class.query.all()


class UserView(BaseView):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseView.__init__('admin/roles.html','User')

    def index(self):
        results = self.get_all_records()
        return render_template(self.template, results=results)
```

I know I could create a get_results method in each subclass but the only thing that would change would be the reference to the class.  DRY suggests that I do this in the base class.

I did find several solutions that allowed me to instantiate a new object from a class name but I need to call a class method not an instance method.

Comment: Declare your method as a class method and you can call it with class name  not with the instance created from the class

Comment: @Arun K:  my problem is the class name is variable (held in a variable passed in to __init__()).  The method is declared as a class method.

Comment: If you have a class instance `foo`, you can use `foo.__class__` to get the class itself.  This will work in Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @Tom Karzes:  but I dont have an instance... all I have is the class name in a variable (as I said before, passed in to another class's __init__ method as a string)

Comment: Hm, well I suppose you could always use `eval(name)` to look up the class given its name as a string.  It's kind of ugly (some people will scream at the use of `eval`), but it should work.

Comment: @TomKarzes NO!!!! ... just use `globals()[classNameStr]` ... or `locals()[classNameString]` or `vars()[classNameStr]` one of them will certainly have it

Comment: @Joran Yeah, I knew someone would scream about that.  My real question is, why does it need to be a string in the first place?  Couldn't the class object itself be passed instead?

Comment: I absolutely agree that the class instance should be passed in instead ...

Comment: Of course.  It never occured to me to just pass in the Class itself.  I was completely over thinking it.  Someone post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I agree that the answer in the duplicate question are the same.  I do not agree however that the question itself is a duplicate.  I googled for a couple of hours and never came across the question you found.  All I was able to find were several ways to import modules by name.